# Count and other calculations on displayed records only

Tags: count, crystal-reports

I am trying to display counts (and other formulas) for only the records being displayed.

When I put count @Field in the report (wherever I put it) I get too many records. I have no suppression formulas present.

I do have formulas in Select Expert, Record. However, I understood that counts should work after these formulas have been applied.

The total number of records showing at the bottom of the report is 799999. When I use count @Field I also get 799999. However, when I export information in Details into excel I get 28140. This is the number of rows of data displayed and what I need to get count etc on.

I have looked at numerous posts re "whileprintingrecords" and "runningtotals" but cannot seem to get anything to work and not sure what I need to do and where?

Thanks
Ian

Comment: What have you tried with running total field?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have discovered that there is an issue with my report so my question is no longer relevant. I have fixed it. Amazing how many times I get this. Spend hours, then post something on here and then have a lightbulb moment on the way home. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your page footer section place text field and there you can place special field 
[image]

and using that "record number" in page footer you can access number of records until that page.

So on page 1 there could be

- Record 5 of 799999

on page 2

- Record 12 of 799999

etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply